# How can I save a file from Firefox to /opt/subdir/ on a Mac?

Tags: mac, firefox, file-management

In Firefox when I right click (Mac: <kbd>Control</kbd>+left click) to bring up the context menu and click "Save link as" Firefox on a Mac pops up a dialog box.

> [image: Screenshot]

If I set the destination to the system drive, and expand the location picker on the left side it lists:

- `Applications`
- `Library`
- `System`
- `Users`

But there's no `/opt/` listed there. I want to store the file in `/opt/mysubdir/`.

Is it possible?

Do I need to start Firefox with `sudo`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? All of the directories you see there — Applications, Library, System and Users — are all user level directories on the main hard drive while `/opt/` is typically a place where optional packages and such are installed on Linux systems. To me this makes no sense why anyone would want to save Firefox downloads to `/opt`.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS does not have an `/opt` folder. Instead, it has the
`/usr/local/opt` folder which you can make visible in the Finder.

[How to access the opt folder on your Mac and make it visible?](https://macpaw.com/how-to/access-opt-folder-on-mac)

> ### How to access the Opt folder using the Finder:
>
> - Open the Finder.
> - Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
>   to open the dialog box
> - Input the following path: `/usr/local/opt`
> - Now, you should have temporary access, so you should be able to drag it into the Finder favorites if you want to access it again.

Doing this will make it available in the Firefox save file dialog.

For more information see this article:

Comment: https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html says to use `/opt/` and... `ls \opt` is there on my Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: It's a Linux manual, not for macOS. It's possible that in some contexts the above was already done for you and `/opt` is an alias to `/usr/local/opt`, but not in Firefox.

Comment: “MacOS does not have an /opt folder.” Nonsense. macOS has a root level `/opt/` directory has had it for years. Proof of this appears in [the official Homebrew docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) where it states, the following for Apple Silicon Macs: `macOS ARM: /opt/homebrew`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 True — though you'll need admin permission to write to it. (But the same applies to `/usr/local/opt`.)